# AWS SAM Local + DynamoDB Local

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm currently testing out AWS SAM with DynamoDB Local using Docker.

Here is the steps that I followed (mostly found in the internet)

1. Create new docker network using `docker network create local-dev`.
2. Run DynamoDB Local `docker run -d -v "$PWD":/dynamodb_local_db -p 8000:8000 --network local-dev --name dynamodb amazon/dynamodb-local`. Until this point, I'm being able to create and list tables using AWS CLI.
3. Then, I proceed with running AWS SAM `sam local start-api --docker-network local-dev`. Everything looks okay.
4. Invoked **lambda.js**, but it looks like no result for `console.log(err)`or `console.log(data)`.

I'm not sure where could it be wrong. Please help me. Thank you in advance!

**lambda.js**

```
const services = require('./services.js');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let options = {
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    region: 'ap-southeast-1',
}

if(process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
  options.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000')
}

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB(options);

exports.getUser = async (event, context) => {

    let params = {};

    dynamoDB.listTables(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
            else console.log(data)
    })

    return true;
}
```

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Serverless Resources


Parameters:

  FunctionsCodeBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: CodeBucket
  FunctionsCodeKey:
    Type: String
    Description: CodeKey
  FunctionsCodeVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: CodeVersion
  NodeEnv:
    Type: String
    Description: NodeEnv

Globals:
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,POST,GET,DELETE,PUT'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,Api-Key,api-key'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  Function:
    Timeout: 300
    Runtime: nodejs10.x
    MemorySize: 128
    CodeUri: ./ 

Resources:
  DevResources:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:                      
      Handler: "index.routes"
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NODE_ENV: !Ref NodeEnv
          # REGION: !Ref "AWS::Region"

      Policies:
      - Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - dynamodb:*
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: "*"
      Events:
        GetUser:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /user
            Method: get
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lambda function does not wait for `dynamoDB.listTables` operation. You can fix this issue by using promisified version of `dynamoDB.listTables` as follows:

```
exports.getUser = async (event, context) => {

  let params = {};

  try {
    const resp = await dynamoDB.listTables(params).promise();
    console.log(resp);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Another thing that you will likely need to do is to assign a network alias to your dynamodb container (you can do that using `--network-alias=<container_name>` option) for example, let's set the alias to `dynamodb`

```
docker run -d -v "$PWD":/dynamodb_local_db -p 8000:8000 --network local-dev --network-alias=dynamodb --name dynamodb amazon/dynamodb-local
```

After that you can use this network alias in your lambda function:

```
if(process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
  options.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('http://dynamodb:8000')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @antonku. I've tried and it works!

Comment: @eFeN You are welcome! I would appreciate if you accept the answer if it resolves the issue, thanks!

Comment: hey i'm getting docker: Error response from daemon: network local-dev not found.

Comment: @user3437721 you will need `docker network create local-dev` first. For Googlers, mind that only user-defined network can use alias, the default bridge won't work, i.e. without `--network blah` command will succeed but alias will not work.